# When is onCreate() called in a non-activity class?

Tags: android, sqlite

I looked up different tutorials about databases and saw, that it was mostly the same approach.
What I don't understand: As I know, onCreate() can ONLY be called automatically by the start of an activity (startActivity(new Intent(this)).
But in the following example, the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper is not an activity but includes the onCreate() method, that never get called manually. How does this work and especially WHEN is its startpoint? Will this be called when you call the constructor? I tried to look this up with logcat and I never got a message, that onCreate() has been called.

I have a class like this:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "title TEXT, "+
                "author TEXT )";

        // create books table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
    }
```

And an external Activity, that handles this class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);


        // add Books
        db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook", "Wei Meng Lee"));
        db.addBook(new Book("Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide", "Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy"));
        db.addBook(new Book("Learn Android App Development", "Wallace Jackson"));

        // get all books
        List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I know, onCreate() can ONLY be called automatically by the start of an activity (startActivity(new Intent(this)).

There are a variety of places in Android where `onCreate()` methods appear, including `Activity`, `Service`, `ContentProvider`, and `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> How does this work

`onCreate()` of a `SQLiteOpenHelper` will be called in response to an `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` call, if and only if the database does not already exist.

Comment: Hello, the two other dudes here say, that it's called when you instantiate the class, will it be called by "getReadableDatabase()" or really when you create the SQLiteOpenHelper object? Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @TrudleR: "the two other dudes here say, that it's called when you instantiate the class" -- not according to [the source code to `SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that both of the classes have a function with the same name doesn't mean that they have something in common.
`onCreate` in `SQLiteOpenHelper` is called when you ask for the database for the first time (with `getReadeableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`)